# IBInspectable run setup function every time IBInspectable value changes

Tags: ios, swift, ibdesignable, ibinspectable

I have an IBDesignable class which has an IBInspectable  value: Int

value is basically the number of balls shown within the IBDesignable class

so I have a setup() func which adds the correct imageViews (one for each ball)  using for _ 0 ..< value { }

But when changing the value  I don't see the new number of balls in Interface Builder

Perhaps But Designables:  Updating  stays there...

How do you make setup() be executed every time Value changes ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: do you see your updates in simulator?

Comment: Running on a device or simulator all appears fine,  Just not in Interface builder while building the view

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
@IBDesignable
class SNButton:UIButton{

    @IBInspectable var val: Int = 0

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()


        for i in 0...val {
         let ui = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: i, y: 0, width: 20, height: 20))
            ui.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
            self.addSubview(ui)
        }
      }        

    }
```

> But I do not advise you to do this because you will notice that
>   storyboard has become very slow